# get next closest(higher) value from Array if not present

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function getClosestValue(standardArray, targetVal) {
standardArray = standardArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        if (!(standardArray) || standardArray.length == 0) {
            return null;}
        if (standardArray.length == 1){
            return standardArray[0];}

        for (var i=1; i<standardArray.length; i++) {
            if (standardArray[i] > targetVal) {
                var prevs = standardArray[i-1];
                var currnt = standardArray[i]
                return Math.abs( prevs-targetVal ) < Math.abs( currnt-targetVal ) ? prev : currnt;
            }
        }
        return standardArray[standardArray.length-1];        
    }

var temp = getClosestValue([110,111,188,190,177,120,140,120,149,148,155], 149)
console.log(temp);
```

I was modifying this code to get the next closest value from array. If the value is there in array then it will return that. If its not there in array then it should return the closest higher value. 
Example: [110, 111, 120, 140, 148, 149, 155, 177, 188, 190] If I search 150, I should get 155 not 149. I tried but finding difficulty in solving this. Could you please help. Thanks **Edited**

Comment: Your logic is taking absolute value so -1 is now 1 so of course it will be closer.

Comment: Be careful with sorting arrays passed to functions as the original order may be important. It may be better to create a copy and work with that instead. Also, the first test should be before you do anything with *standardArray* since your first statement assumes the tests are true. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting your for loop with `i` set to 1, implying you want to start on the second element in the array. However, your comparison `standardArray[i] > targetVal` ignores the fact that `standardArray[i-1]` (`prevs`) could be less than 0.

I've update your example with new starting index and variable names:

```
function getClosestValue(standardArray, targetVal) {
standardArray = standardArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        if (!(standardArray) || standardArray.length == 0) {
            return null;}
        if (standardArray.length == 1){
            return standardArray[0];}

        for (var i=0; i<standardArray.length-1; i++) {
            if (standardArray[i] >= targetVal) {
                var curr = standardArray[i];
                var next = standardArray[i+1]
                return Math.abs( curr-targetVal ) < Math.abs( next-targetVal ) ? curr : next;
            }
        }
        return standardArray[standardArray.length-1];        
    }

var temp = getClosestValue([110,111,188,190,177,120,140,120,149,148,155], 149)
console.log(temp);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add, It should return the number if it has the same number. If I enter 149, since 149 is there in array. It should return it. If the value is not there in array then it should return the closest higher value.

Comment: Updated answer. `standardArray[i] > targetVal` simply becomes `standardArray[i] >= targetVal`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```js
function getClosestValue(input, array){
  var tempArray = array;
  var index = tempArray.sort().findIndex((item) => {
    return input < item;
  });
  if(index >= 0) {
    return array[index]; 
  } else {
    return null; // no answer
  }
}

var ary = [110, 111, 120, 140, 148, 149, 155, 177, 188, 190];

console.log(getClosestValue(150,ary));
```

You start by sorting the array. (It might be unsorted). Then you find the first item with a value larger than the input. Then just return that index's value.

Comment: I believe OP wants the closest value that is greater than the input. So you should return `array[index]`.

Comment: @csp713 good catch, it was a silly bunder, the answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that after you sort the array, you just want the first value that is equal to or higher than *targetVal*, or the highest element in the array.

Sorting affects the array in place, so best to copy, then sort, then [*find*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first value that meets the "equal to or larger than" criterion, or if not met, just return the highest value (last in the sorted array) e.g.:

```js
function getNextHighest(arr, val) {
  return arr.slice().sort().find((x,i,a) => i < a.length-1? x >= val : x);
}

var data = [110,111,188,190,177,120,140,120,149,148,155];
    
console.log(getNextHighest(data, 149));
console.log(getNextHighest(data, 120));
console.log(getNextHighest(data, 1000));
```

In the original code:

```
function getClosestValue(standardArray, targetVal) {

  // This assumes that standardArray is an array
  standardArray = standardArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});

  // Then there is a test for it. The test should be first.
  if (!(standardArray) || standardArray.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }

  if (standardArray.length == 1){
        return standardArray[0];
  }

  // Why start at 1?
  for (var i=1; i<standardArray.length; i++) {

    if (standardArray[i] > targetVal) {
      var prevs = standardArray[i-1];
      var currnt = standardArray[i];

      // This logic is unnecessary since the array is sorted, the first
      // higher value is the one required.
      // Also, the logic doesn't seem appropriate for what you want as it will
      // return the previous (lower) value if it's closer than the higher one
      return Math.abs(prevs - targetVal) < Math.abs(currnt - targetVal) ? prev : currnt;

      // So instead just return the higher value, replace the above with
      // return standardArray[i];
    }
  }

  // Otherwise it returns the last element in the array or undefined
  return standardArray[standardArray.length-1];        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well.

```js
function getClosestValue(array, targetValue){
  if(array.indexOf(targetValue) != -1){ 
       return targetValue;
  }
  else{
    var tempValue;
    for(var i=0; 1 < array.length; i++){
        array = array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
        if(array[i] > targetValue){
           return array[i];
        }
    }
  }
}
var value = getClosestValue([110,111,188,190,177,120,140,120,148,155], 149);
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need bit of amendment in above given answer to get next closest value.

**First sort your array numerically**

```
// numberAs function will sort numeric array in asscending order
function numberAs(a,b) {
  return a-b;
}

function getClosestValue(input, array){
  // When you sort your array as numerically then you will able to get exact closest position of next higher value.
 // If you don't sort your array numerically then you will get 110 instead of getting 90 when search value 1 in array 
  var index = array.sort(numberAs).findIndex((item) => {
  return input < item;
   });
  if(index > 0) {
    return array[index]; 
  } else {
    return null; // no answer
  }
}

var ary = [110,90, 111, 1, 170, 180, 120, 140, 148, 149, 177, 155, 188, 190];

console.log(getClosestValue(1,ary));
```